# Using Nikon AF D lens on D7200 - Aside from setting it to minimum aperature, anything else before mounting?

Tags: nikon

I'm not exactly a Nikon shooter, so pardon the newbie question.

I'm eyeing a cheap nifty-fifty for my dad, who owns a D7200. I did have a quick look at the manual, and it suggests that for the AF 50mm f1.8 D, I should be setting it to minimum aperture before mounting it.

I presume the camera body can still electronically change the aperture once mounted?

Any other pitfalls I need to know about? I can get the D cheaper than the G, so that's kinda nice.

Comment: Remember that the 50mm is a full frame lenses and more like an 80mm on that 7200. Will feel tighter than intended, won't shoot like a nifty fifty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikon's own specifications state that your D7200 is compatible with AF-D lenses. There is no exception or caveat that excludes the 50mm f1.8 D. http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7200/spec.htm

In addition to setting the lens at the minimum aperture, f/22 in this case, there is a slider to lock that setting:

[image]

Once the aperture is set to f/22, be certain to move the slider to align the orange dots. You should be all set.

I have and use this very lens and I think it is quite excellent, especially at its remarkable price.

Comment: Yeah I saw it on sale, it’s like 80CAD less (used) compared to a G.